# Why can't I access Chrome built-in function $?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

Type `$` in Chrome console then <kbd>return</kbd>:

```
$;
function () { [native code] }
```

And to get a DOM element:

```
$("container");
<div class=​"container" id=​"container">​…​</div>​
```

But it cannot work in script block:

```
window.onload = function  (argument) {
    var container = $("container");
    Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
}
```

Comment: You have included the jQuery-library? As far as I know, you can't use $ like that in pure js.

Comment: $ is not a built in function. It is used in the popular jquery library.

Answer (score 11):

You're getting the error because that, while the Google Chrome Console has its own $ shortcut operator, it's not available to the original window:

[Chrome Developer Tools: Console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console)

If you want functionality like that in your application, you'll need to include some other library (jQuery is the popular choice around here but there are others like Prototype, MooTools, etc) or you could simply rip the function out of the jQuery console if that's all you need.

Answer (score 3):

By looking at the actual contents of the `$` function in the Chrome console, one can infer that it is in fact nothing more than a "toolbox function" built into the Console by the Chrome developers. Since it's in the the console, you can't access it from the window available to you.

Said contents:

```
function $(element) {
  if (arguments.length > 1) {
    for (var i = 0, elements = [], length = arguments.length; i < length; i++)
      elements.push($(arguments[i]));
    return elements;
  }
  if (Object.isString(element))
    element = document.getElementById(element);
  return Element.extend(element);
}
```